# Pi 4 Model B: failed to connect to network

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-4

I bought Pi 4 Model B recently from an official seller.

Then I installed `raspberry pi OS 32 bit` as it was mentioned on site.

I completed the installation setup and **everything was working fine**! **Wi-Fi was working fine too..**

After 3 days when I turned it back on surprisingly it was not connecting to my network through Wi-Fi!

I could not figure out why this was happening so I reinstalled the OS and now during setup I get this message while connecting to WIFI:  **`Failed to connect to Network`**

I double checked password for my router, everything matches.

Is this problem normal for the Pi? I am worried about whether my Pi is damaged.
[image]

---

### Here's an update to this issue

I tried connecting a **Wi-Fi adapter** and after a quick reboot the internet got connected through it. But I am still having no luck with the on-board Wi-Fi:
[image].

---

After disconnecting the Wi-Fi adapter surprisingly the onboard Wi-Fi picks up the already connected network. I rechecked by rebooting the Pi multiple times and it is working fine now!

---

### EDIT:

It worked fine for sometimes! NOW it's not working!!

Comment: Did you get the language up?  It's needed for WiFi to work.  Also a reboot of the router may help.

Comment: @Andyroo Well I did complete the language and country setup  successfully, there was no error message there. I tried rebooting the router too.. it's not working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why but this worked for me! This method is quite strange though I don't take guarantee that it will work in all situations, it's just that it worked for me.

I urgently needed the internet connection on pi 4b so what I did was I connected a `usb wifi adapter` I had lying around.
It took some time for pi to recognize it and after a quick reboot the **network got connected through adapter!**
After my work on pi was done I removed the adapter and connected it to my desktop.
When I came back to shutdown the pi I noticed that the pi was still connected to network. I was quite shocked!

**I don't know how! but this works!**

### EDIT:

It worked fine for sometimes! NOW it's not working!!

### EDIT:

**According to:** [This post!](https://www.enricozini.org/blog/2019/himblick/raspberry-pi-4-loses-wifi-at-2560x1440-screen-resolution/) `dated: 2019-11-27 13:23`

It appears that pi 4, until an update is released, `will have wifi connecting problems on higher resolutions`. **you need to bootup your pi at lower resolutions (for me it worked at 640 * 480)**. **`After booting you can switch to high resolution!`**.
I tried other resolutions too but for me 640 * 480 only works!

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.

Comment: @Ingo I almost forgot about this :)